# Reference to generic trait with asscociated type as struct field

Tags: rust

I am struggling to convince Rust to accept a reference to an instance implementing a generic trait with associated type as a value of struct field. Could you please give some clues what is wrong in the code below.

```rust
trait TraitA{}

trait TraitB{
    type As: TraitA;
}

struct StructA;

impl TraitA for StructA{}

struct StructB;

impl TraitB for StructB{
    type As = StructA;
}

struct StructC<'a> {
    r: &'a (dyn TraitB<As = (dyn TraitA)> + 'a),
}


fn main(){
    let x = StructB;
    let z = StructC {
        r: &x,
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=53411b5bb5807079ff6bb07adb61819a)

Comment: I have simplified code example following comment from Pavel Arnold.

Answer (score 1):

#### About posted compiler error

The problem caused be the fact that `TCPtransport` does not implement 
`Transport<.., Configuration=(dyn TransportConfiguration<SyncReq>>`, 
instead it implements
`Transport<.., Configuration=TcpTranportCfg>`, and later one cannot be casted to former:

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=185e9a73e5fb9a336e8f786eee610e1e)

Possible solution: Add new trait (Basically to strip associated type info):

```rust
trait SyncReqTransport{
    ...
}

impl<T> SyncReqTransport<SyncReq> for T 
    where 
        T: Transport<SyncReq>, // I Removed other parameters for simplicity
        <T as Transport<SyncReq>>::Config: TransportConfiguration<SyncReq>
{
    ...
}
```

And change `DAG` to

```
pub struct DAG<'a, T> {
    request_transport: &'a (dyn SyncReqTransport + 'a),
}
```

#### Another problem

`sr_transport` being created on stack, and later reference to it being returned from 
the function it is created, which is illegal.

Comment: thank you for having a look. You playground example produces different error from Rust compiler. I have modified it to return the very same error I get in my code: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=53411b5bb5807079ff6bb07adb61819a). So the question is why Rust compiler do not see that StryctA have TraitA implemented and satisfy requirements for field `r` of `StructC` ?

Comment: You can have trait with method taking reference to associated type. If you could do this cast, then instead of expected concrete type you would be allowed to pass reference any trait implementor. Then, inside the implementation of this method, call to any method that specific to the struct, but not trait would be illegal.